# Account for different region

Tags: league-of-legends

I registered account in Legue of Legends. I was not asked at which server I want to create account. That account allows me only to login "EU Nordic & East" server. Is it possible to login with that account on other server then "EU Nordic & East" ? If yes how? If not, how can I create account for other server?

SOLVED: I found the place Where I can switch region on registration page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, however you'll have to pay for a server transfer.

You can find the server transfer option in the shop (on the **Other** tab), and can relocate your account to any region.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the account will only exist on one server. You can not switch back and forth for free.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use your main account you will have to do a server transfer. For some servers this is free, while for others there is a small amount of RP you have to pay.

If you just want to create an account you can visit the homepage of LoL and there you can choose a region where you can register a new account.

[image]

After you've created your account you have to choose the server you've created it on in the launcher

[image]

Note that you need a special permission to play on Asian servers